# What is the correct format to pass a javascript function parameter using the kendo ui framework?

Tags: kendo-ui

I have image links dynamically generated with a kendo datasource and I need to call a function that uses the id...

How do you format the href to call the javascript function with the parameter?

See my attempt here: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cIfVlpVYUH

Thanks

Comment: downvoted because you posted a video which takes a whole minute to watch, and still doesn't make the situation clear, instead of code which would take 5-10 seconds to read. Your job as a questioner is to make your question easy to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your anchor tag like below

```
<a href="javascript:getItems(${id})">...</a>
```

then, getItems() method will call. for example,

```
function getItems(value){
   // use value as you wish
}
```

then, you can get 'id' value as parameter.

Comment: Did you use above anchor tag within kendo template as you mentioned in the video?